# MBProgressHUD and Storyboard instantiate new view controller

Tags: ios, uiview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, mbprogresshud

I am using [MBRProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) with a storyboard setup.

I present a Login view controller which handles the login. Once a user is received I present another view controller like this:

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
```

Within my login method I create my HUD with the following:

```
// Start the HUD outside the user login block
self.HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
self.HUD.dimBackground = NO;
self.HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"HUDLoggingInText", @"Login HUD Logging in text");
```

This all works fine the issue I have is with dismissing the view controller. Before using storyboards I was able to add the following:

```
// Bring down the HUD with a success message
self.HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]];
self.HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
self.HUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"HUDLoggedInText", @"HUD Logged in text");
[self.HUD hide:YES afterDelay:2];
```

This would bring down the HUD with a success checkmark and different text. The issue I have now is that when the HomeVC is loaded using the first line of code above the Login view controller (and the navigation controller it lives on) is deallocated which I think means the HUD is lost too.

How can I have the HUD show the success before `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`? I have tried the obvious moving the HUD part before the load of the HomeVC but this makes no difference, neither does changing the delay to 0.

**EDIT**
Views loaded. The first view the storyboard loads is the class InitialViewController. This then instaniates another controller based on if the user is logged in:

```
    self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeVC"];
} else {
    NSLog(@"logged in");
    self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
```

The initial View controller always remains on the stack and is an ECSlidingViewController so it has a property for the topViewController.

Ideally I need to know how to add the HUD to this initialViewController on the stack, I guess rather than the currently displayed view (Login View Controller) as that is deallocated when the login is complete and a new view controller loaded with '`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`' again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HUD should not be lost. You just lose the reference to it if the controller holding the reference is deallocated.

Solution: just pass the reference to the HUD to your home view controller. Or create the home view controller before (without showing it) and do all the HUD logic in there.

To pass the reference:

```
self.topViewController.hud = hud;
```

Comment: Correct, I guessed that was the case. However, how do I get a pointer to the Home View Controller that is on the view stack, based on the information in the question? Or to the initial view controller that is loaded first and remains on the stack always. Question updated.

Comment: Actually, you do not even need a reference to the HUD. All the MBRProgressHUD calls are anyway class methods. You can simply dismiss the HUD and put up a new one *without* retaining any reference to it.

Comment: could you explain more about what you mean/ what i should do?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD under "Usage" to see how to dismiss it. You do not need a reference.

Comment: I understand how to dismiss it, the issue is that when the new view controller is instantiated the old view controller (view) that has the HUD displayed is removed therefore removing the HUD before I can display the logged in message with checkmark

Comment: My answer already contains the solution. This site is not suitable for a chatting format to problem solving.

Comment: Ok, how do I 'pass the reference to the HUD to your home view controller' please?

Comment: This does not work as there is no reference to the topViewController within the Login View Controller. I can include the "InitialViewController' and access the property through self.slidingViewController.topViewController.hud but this does not work either. I have accepted answer and made a new question around this with more information (and slightly different to this) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071183/how-to-reference-storyboard-creating-view-controllers-from-other-vcs